# error during e2e tests: USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

To run e2e tests I'm using Protractor with Jasmine framework.
Recently I was forced tu update chromedriver to version 87.0.4280.20. And I'm faced with this error now.
I cannot decrease chromedriver version because of the used version of Chrome.
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Same problem here...